# Having trouble using Javascript to pull item attributes from a list

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of items from a page and I'm simply trying to pull some of their attributes (such as name and link URL).  Here's an example of a list element:

```html
<li class="item">
    <a href="http://URL.com" title="Title Item 1" class="image-URL"><img src="http://image.url.com" alt="Title Item 1"></a>

    <div class="details">
        <p class="name">
            <a href="http://URL.com">Title Item 1</a>
        </p>
    
    </div>
</li>
```

How would I get the title from this?

I know I can call item.findElementsByClassName("name"), but that gives me the whole element ,instead of just the text "Title Item 1"

Additionally, is there a way to get the link URL (http://URL.com) as well?

Comment: Can you just use `id` on the `a` element to catch it's attributes?

Comment: Text is fetched on an element with `myElement.textContent`. Common attributes can generally be fetched as a property, so if you already have the `<a>` element, then `myAnchor.href`. More broadly, the DOM is an object tree representation of the page. You can traverse through the objects just alike any JS objects, and read or change their properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `querySelector()` function to get the `a` element and then use `getAttribute()` on that element to get which attribute you want.

Every element in DOM has its appropriate `object` with which you can work and access it's properties.

But for `href` and `content` there are appropriate properties via which you can get them. Use `href` and `textContent` properties to get them.

With `querySelector`, if you don't have `id`

```js
var link = document.querySelector('.details a');

console.log(link.href, link.textContent);
```

```html
<li class="item">
    <a href="http://URL.com" title="Title Item 1" class="image-URL"><img src="http://image.url.com" alt="Title Item 1"></a>

    <div class="details">
        <p class="name">
            <a href="http://URL.com">Title Item 1</a>
        </p>
    
    </div>
</li>
```

With `getElementById` if you have set `id`

```js
var link = document.getElementById('myLink');

console.log(link.href, link.textContent);
```

```html
<li class="item">
    <a href="http://URL.com" title="Title Item 1" class="image-URL"><img src="http://image.url.com" alt="Title Item 1"></a>

    <div class="details">
        <p class="name">
            <a id="myLink" href="http://URL.com">Title Item 1</a>
        </p>
    
    </div>
</li>
```

Why use `textContent` and not `innerHTML` with plain text ?

`innerHTML` - parses content as HTML and takes longer.

`textContent` - uses straight text, does not parse HTML, and is faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a id='someID' href="http://URL.com">Title Item 1</a>

var url=document.getElementById("someID").getAttribute('href');
var title=document.getElementById("someID").textContent;
```

Comment: You're calling methods that don't exist on DOM elements.

Comment: Sorry Confused with JQuery @squint

Comment: No problem. Just change `.text()` to `.textContent`, and change `ByID` to `ById`, and you'll be set.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.